# Filter Objectify query by "key" field

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have the following Objectify relationship:

```
@Entity(“Author”)
public class Author{
  @Id
  private long authorId;
  …

}

@Entity(“Book”)
public class Book{
  @Id
  private long id;
  private Key<Author> authorKey;
  …

}
```

Now for the fun part: I have the `authorId` (the id, not entity) and I need to query Book for that author. My query is below, but it is returning an empty list, whereas I know for a fact that this author has books in the datastore. So how might I fix this query?

```
public static List<Book> getBooksForAuthor(Long authorId) {
    Key<Author> authorKey = Key.create(Author.class, authorId);
    return OfyService.ofy().load().type(Book.class).filter("authorKey", authorKey).order(“-date").list();
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying with the field `authorId` instead of the `authorKey` that you just created.

```
OfyService.ofy().load().type(Book.class).filter("authorKey", authorKey).order(“-date").list();
```

With this change and the index in place, you should get the result.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am actually using the `authorKey`. That was part of my troubleshooting.

Comment: did you rewrite your entity after you added the index ?

datastore docs- 
_..changing a property from unindexed to indexed does not affect any existing entities that may have been created before the change. Queries filtering on the property will not return such existing entities, because the entities weren't written to the query's index when they were created. To make the entities accessible by future queries, you must rewrite them to the Datastore so that they will be entered in the appropriate indexes._

Comment: I had no idea about the rewrite thing. Unfortunately, just editing the entity right in the console does not work. I actually have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `@Index` the `Book.authorKey` and `Book.date` fields. I can't remember offhand if this will require a multiproperty index on {authorKey, date}, but try without and see if it works.

I would also recommend that you call the field 'author' not 'authorKey'.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I created the index in the `datastore-indexes.xml` file. Also I placed `@Index` on both authorKey and date. But I still get an empty result set.

Comment: Also, on the authorKey I have two annotations `@Index
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)`. Will they interfere with each other? I don't want the client to see the authorKey so I am hiding it from them with `ApiResourceProperty`.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for re-enforcing the `@Index`. I wasn't too sure about them.

Comment: The multiproperty indexes in `datastore-indexes.xml` are built automatically for you. The single property indexes flagged with `@Index` are established when you save a particular entity; merely adding the annotation will not change the data in the datastore. You must resave each specific entity.

Comment: oh also: I can't imagine how @ApiResourceProperty could interact in any way with Objectify's annotations. Objectify certainly doesn't look at 'foreign' annotations.